# NSArray objects addresses

Tags: ios, objective-c

So unlike C where an array = &array = &array[0], was trying to have a quick look at the structure of a NSArray and how its objects were stored and have a question with the below code.

```
NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"abc"];
NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"xyz"];
NSString *str3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"123"];
NSMutableArray *someArray = (NSMutableArray*)@[@"1",@"2",@"3"];

NSMutableArray *original = (NSMutableArray*)@[str1, str2, [someArray mutableCopy]]; 

NSMutableArray *deep = [original mutableCopy];

[[original objectAtIndex:2] addObject:str3];

for (id obj in original) {
    NSLog(@"\nIn Original:: \nvalue is:%@, at :%p; Address of object: %p\n",obj, obj, &obj);
}
for (id obj in deep) {
    NSLog(@"\nIn Deep:: \nvalue is:%@, at :%p; Address of object: %p\n",obj, obj, &obj);
}

NSLog(@"\n Address of Original : %p \n", &original);
NSLog(@"\n Address IN Original : %p \n", original);
NSLog(@"\n Address in first object of original : %p \n", [original objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Sample o/p.

In Original::

object is:abc, at :0x7f8a5a58e750; Address of object pointer is : 0x7fff50cdd750

object is:xyz, at :0x7f8a5a58ff70; Address of object pointer is : 0x7fff50cdd750

object is:(
    1,
    2,
    3,
    123
), at :0x7f8a5a591200; Address of object: 0x7fff50cdd750

In Deep::

object is:abc, at :0x7f8a5a58e750; Address of object pointer is : 0x7fff50cdd708

object is:xyz, at :0x7f8a5a58ff70; Address of object pointer is : 0x7fff50cdd708

object is:(
    1,
    2,
    3,
    123
), at :0x7f8a5a591200; Address of object pointer: 0x7fff50cdd708

Address of Original : 0x7fff50cdd760

Address IN Original : 0x7f8a5a591230

Address in first object of original : 0x7f8a5a58e750

Im getting the same address for &obj for all the elements in the arrays above. Anything Im missing here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Copy and paste that actual real NSLog output into your question.

Comment: Keep in mind that your `deep` variable is actually a shallow copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `obj` is a pointer which holds the address of another variable. If you change the value of that pointer it won't change it's address. In details,

```
id obj = original[0];
```

If you use

```
NSLog(@"%p",obj);
```

It'll print the address of the object contained in original[0]. And if you use

```
NSLog(@"%p",&obj);
```

It'll print the address of obj.

So even if you change the value like:

```
obj = original[1];    
NSLog(@"%p",&obj);
```

Will give you same pointer address (Address of obj is not changing only the value of obj is changing)

Comment: Thanks. Im aware of this as is evident in the other part of my question and of course, using fast enumeration, the address of obj1 would be the same for all the elements...hasty oversight...thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

`-[NSArray mutableCopy]` doesn't do a deep copy. Even if it did, those are constant strings you're trying to copy. `NSString` is immutable, so actually making a copy would be a waste of time and memory.

Comment: As an aside `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"some constant string"]` is silly: this just returns the constant string. It might make sense if you were trying to create a mutable string from a constant, but in that case you should use `stringWithString:`, not `stringWithFormat:`

Comment: I realize -[NSArray mutableCopy] doesn't do a deep copy. Your surmise that I am testing the later is incorrect. Likewise with "stringWithFormat"...a mutableCopy returns a copy of the constant.

Comment: I don't understand what you're expecting to happen, then. `[@[@"string"] mutableCopy]` does _not_ make a copy of that literal string, if that's what your last sentence means.

Comment: StringWithString: or stringWithFormat: will result in a new pointer to the same literal. Likewise in directly attempting to copy a string literal. A mutableCopy of its pointer will result in a copy of its value, the string literal in this case.

Comment: `NSString * s = @"string"; NSString * t = s` results in a new pointer to the same literal, as well, with completely equivalent results. `t = [NSString stringWithString:s];` is wasted typing and a wasted cycle for the message send.

Comment: NSString * t = [s mutableCopy];

Comment: And yes, don't disagree about stringWithString: usage and in fact, that is what I had stated earlier. Notice that I haven't used it. :)

Comment: `[@"string" mutableCopy]` returns an `NSMutableString`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a deep copy on an array, you need to do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *copiedArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for (id obj in originalArray) {
    [copiedArray addObject:[obj copy]];
}
```

Of course, this only works if all of the objects in your array support NSCopying.

You could get clever and make a category on NSArray that does something similar. You should check, though, that all of your objects conform to NSCopying.